# How to wrap text around a graphic in beamer inside a block

Tags: beamer, wrapfigure, block

I have the following code:

```
    \begin{block}{ROC-Curve}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{0.5/textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,height=0.3 
    \textheight,keepaspectratio]{ROC_curve.PNG}
    True Positives-Rate (TPR) = $\frac{TP}{TP + FN}\\
    False Positives-Rate(FPR) = $\frac{FP}{TP + TN}$ \\
    An ROC-Curve plots TPR vs FPR at different classification thresholds.
    Adjusting the classification threshold leads therefore to a change in
    both TPR and FPR. 
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \end{block}
```

Ideally it would align the text around the picture within the block...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why are you using `wrapfig` here? Could you please make your code compilable, i.e. produce a document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled. And perhaps add a sketch that shows what you're after.

Comment: Hi marmot, thanks for responding. I just use wrapfig, because I dont know anything else... I am currently using a non-standard beamer theme so it would probably be quite cumbersome to load it. Do you have any other suggestion besides wrapfig?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you should use `wrapfig` here. You could just use columns to arrange the pic and the text in two, er, columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{block}{ROC-Curve}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.33\linewidth}
~\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.6\linewidth}
    True Positives-Rate (TPR) = $\frac{TP}{TP + FN}$

    False Positives-Rate(FPR) = $\frac{FP}{TP + TN}$

    An ROC-Curve plots TPR vs FPR at different classification thresholds.
    Adjusting the classification threshold leads therefore to a change in
    both TPR and FPR. 
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]